# Creates element to the HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script

```
var item = document.createElement('LI');
var title = document.createElement('A');
title.href = '#';
title.className = 'service-tag';
title.innerHTML = titleText;
item.appendChild(title);
panel.appendChild(item);
```

Script above will create html code like this

```
 <li><a href="#" class="service-tag">Some title</a></li>
```

with `titleText` is `Some title`

So I want create below html code like

```
<li data-genre="Some title"><a href="#" class="service-tag">Some title</a></li>
```

How can I add `data-genre="Some title"` into `<li>` like html code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
  var titleText = "something";
  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  var item = document.createElement('LI');
  att = document.createAttribute("data-genre");
  att.value = "some";
  item.setAttributeNode(att);
  var title = document.createElement('A');
  title.href = '#';
  title.className = 'service-tag';
  title.innerHTML = titleText;
  item.appendChild(title);
  panel.appendChild(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
item.setAttribute("data-genre", "Some title");
```

```js
var panel = document.createElement('UL');
var titleText = "some title";
var item = document.createElement('LI');
item.setAttribute("data-genre", "Some title");
var title = document.createElement('A');
title.href = '#';
title.className = 'service-tag';
title.innerHTML = titleText;
item.appendChild(title);
panel.appendChild(item);
document.body.appendChild(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
var item = document.createElement('LI');
var title = document.createElement('A');
title.setAttribute('data-genre', 'Some title')
title.href = '#';
title.className = 'service-tag';
title.innerHTML = titleText;
item.appendChild(title);
panel.appendChild(item);
```

What you missed is, `setAttribute`. You can set any attribute using this.